# Not routing to the namespaced controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to set the root url after the user logs in but the problem is after the user logs in they are redirected to the home page but not the page I want. Here is the code.

```
devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      # root to: 'dashboard#index', module: 'client'
      namespace :client do
        root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard
      end
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

The user should have been redirected to /client/index instead it gets redirected to \ .

Comment: Devise already handles this with the after_sign_in_path_for method. Just override that method in your controller (ApplicationController, presumably) and have it return whatever path you want.

Comment: @TomL , Yup I have done that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get it working.

```
namespace :client do
    get 'dashboard/index'
  end

  devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    # authenticated :user do
    #   # root to: 'dashboard#index', module: 'client'
    #   namespace :client do
    #     root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard
    #   end
    # end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

If there is a better way , please let me know